# Linking jQuery to a Button

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I have the following jQuery script which I am using to check and uncheck all the checkboxes in a table (there are four tables and I need one for each table).

```
$("#TAB1-check").click(function() {
    $(".TAB1").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
```

How can I link this to a button called "TAB1-check"?

```
<input type="button" value="Check All" id="TAB1-check" class="TAB1"/>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your code seems fine, except that you need to use ` $(".TAB1").attr('checked', 'checked');` to check all the checkboxes having "TAB1" class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JASHy/)

```
<input type="button" value="Un-check All" id="TAB1-check" class="TAB1" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="TAB1" />
    <script>
        $("#TAB1-check").click(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            if (value == "Check All") {
                $(".TAB1").attr('checked', true);
                $(this).val("Un-check All");
            }
            else if(value == "Un-check All") {
                $(".TAB1").attr('checked', false);
                $(this).val("Check All");
            }
        });
    </script>
```

of course `this.checked` is not gonna work with an `button` as others said, So you will have to make some changes in your script.

Comment: Hi yogi - I like your solution - by default my page loads with all the checkboxes checked.  I've tried to reverse your script, but did not work - any chance you could tweak it please?

Comment: @DustinCook See edit just put `Un-check All` in button's value on load

Comment: thanks for that... this script won't check the boxes again when the user tells it to uncheck the boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this.checked` on a button. You need some other variable to indicate whether the checkboxes should be checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use

```
<button type="button" id="TAB1-check" class="TAB1">Check all</button>
```

The button works almost the same as a anchor. (There will be no submitting)